# AnimateWithDuration block is not correct

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to animate an UIView with AnimateWithDuration block. This UIView contains two UIScrollViews and two buttons. One Button is filter down and the other is filterUP. Like the picture :

[image]

So scrolling down I use this block :

```
@IBAction func FilterEntry(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.FilterDown.hidden = true
    self.FilterDownIcon.hidden = true

    var duration = 0.5
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
        self.ColouredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 65, width: 400, height: 212)

        }, completion: { finished in
            self.FilterUPIcon.hidden = true
            self.FilterUP.hidden = true
            self.DateScroll.hidden = false
            self.EventScroll.hidden = false
            self.FilterUPIcon.hidden = false
            self.FilterUP.hidden = false
     })
}
```

that works fine and it scrolls quite nice. but when I go the other way, so the UIView goes up, then the UIView goes up fine but the removal of the UIScollviews last till the end of the animatation and then disappear. I can see by the code that this make sense, but when it goes down it runs smooth but going up it looks dreadful.

Here is my code that brings the UIView up :

```
 @IBAction func FilterUPEvent(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.FilterUP.hidden = true
        self.FilterUPIcon.hidden = true

        var duration = 0.5
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
            self.ColouredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 65, width: 400, height: 20)

            }, completion: { finished in

                self.EventScroll.hidden = true
                self.DateScroll.hidden = true
                self.FilterUP.hidden = true
                self.FilterUPIcon.hidden = true
                self.FilterDown.hidden = false
                self.FilterDownIcon.hidden = false
        })
 }
```

[image]

Comment: What's the question? Also, if you want to _scroll_, why are you changing the _frame_ of something?

Comment: Hi, it scrolls lovely going down, but going up it scrolls the background fine but then just removes the UIScrollViews abruptly. It makes sense because in the closure blocks i have set them to hidden. but going down it seems quite smooth.

Comment: You could use `alpha` property of a `UIView` in the animation block to fade in and fade out views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `self.colouredSquare.clipToBounds = true` above the animation block.

> clipToBounds is a Boolean value that determines whether subviews are
>   confined to the bounds of the view. Setting this value to true causes
>   subviews to be clipped to the bounds of the receiver. If set to false,
>   subviews whose frames extend beyond the visible bounds of the receiver
>   are not clipped. The default value is false.